# Generic conversion in Java

Tags: java

I thing I have a design problem

I get as an input :

- list : `List<String>` of type for example `"java.lang.string"` ...
- a data string

I want to verify if data is of type `list.get(i)` dynamically

To be clearer :

I get from database a list as the following `list= {"java.lang.String", 'java.lang.Integer"}`

and I get a `String` data "123". I want to verify that data is an instance of `list.get(1)`. My list and my data values are dynamic and can change.

Comment: You can use List<Object>

Comment: What exactly do you need to verify? "The data is of type list.get(i)" is not clear.

Comment: So, your list is a list of strings that are the names of classes like `java.lang.String`?

Comment: Yes and the content of the list can change

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, the list is not of the type `List<String>`, that's visible only at the level of static type calculations and pertains to the static type of *expressions*, not dynamic type of *instances*.

At runtime the list is of some type implementing `List` (say, `ArrayList`) and it simply *contains* objects of one type or another. The type could be anything.

So the way to make your check general must be based on reflection. You'll have to retrieve the class by `Class.forName(String)` and then use `Class.isInstance(Object)` to check whether an object is of that type.

Comment: I think reflection is a good idea. But I still have to specify a treatement to every type in the list. So, if one day I get a new type, I ll have to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have something like `List<Object>`, why not convert this to a class with a list for each type in your original list, eg.

```
class HeapsOfLists {

 List<String> strings;
 List<Float> floats;
 List<Double> doubles;//.. ect
}
```

Just sort all the instances into their according list, can even do a nice little group by class in the new java streams, or `instanceof` ect..
But that's just my 2cents. In other programming languages you have parameter matching which is built for this sort of thing (sort of). It's never going to be very eligant when you have different types in the same collection and then need to ask each guy, hey what the hell are you!?!?!?

You will always need to add new code for new types, and this is why there are interfaces to stop this problem. It is like this for a purpose though!(It's not that java is a bad language). It is so the jvm can run faster and optimize the code better!

I always like to think of java as a layer on top of a language closer to the computer hardware, but not too far away like python or something! So that way you can still write code which is very fast!

Answer (score 0):

Shall we assume a method `boolean isValueOfType(String value, String className)`?

- `assertTrue(isValueOfType("123", "java.lang.Integer"))`
- `assertFalse(isValueOfType("ABC", "java.lang.Integer"))`?

I don't see any way of achieving this checking without code that applies per class as suggested above by Marko.

You could achieve it reasonably simply with a map of functions that try and convert `value` to the type: -

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Converters {
    private final Map<String, Function<String, Boolean>> converters;

    Converters() {
        converters = new HashMap<>();
        converters.put("java.lang.String", (v) -> true);
        converters.put("java.lang.Integer", (v) -> {
            try {
                Integer.valueOf(v);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isValueOfType(String value, String className) {
        Function<String, Boolean> converter = converters.get(className);
        return converter.apply(value);
    }
}
```

And a unit-test

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ConvertersTest {
    @Test
    public void testInteger() {
        Converters converters = new Converters();
        Assert.assertTrue(converters.isValueOfType("123", "java.lang.Integer"));
        Assert.assertFalse(converters.isValueOfType("ABC", "java.lang.Integer"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testString() {
        Converters converters = new Converters();
        Assert.assertTrue(converters.isValueOfType("123", "java.lang.String"));
        Assert.assertTrue(converters.isValueOfType("ABC", "java.lang.String"));
    }
}
```

The above maybe overkill but is basically a lookup table of types and appropriate converter methods.

If you can't use Java 8 (lambdas) then something similar can be achieved with normal interfaces.

Comment: Of course, you could replace the Map with a `switch(className)` construct